# Using a vector to subset from columns

Tags: r

Currently my data looks like this:

```
head(data)
Person                Statute            Statute2
1                     21 O.S. 1           22 O.S. 3
2                     21 O.S. 14          NA
3                     22 O.S. 3           NA
```

I am trying to create a new column which categorizes cases as violent or non-violent. (If any one of the statutes in the row is violent, the column should indicate VIOLENT)

```
Person                Statute           Statute2            Type
1                     21 O.S. 1         22 O.S. 3           Violent
2                     21 O.S. 14        NA                  Non-violent
3                     22 O.S. 3         NA                  Violent
```

I created a vector for my violent offenses:

```
violent <- c("22 O.S. 3", "24 O.S. 6", "22 O.S. 16")
```

I'm trying to figure out how to code my non-violent offenses as non-violent. I can't do it one by one like the violent one because there are way too many cases. I've tried:

```
nonviolent <- function(x) {
!(violent)
}
```

But it didn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Look into the `%in%` function and see if you determine how that will serve your needs. For example, how might you use the `%in%` function to check your two variables and then use that to set a new variable?

Comment: That seems to work! It returns an output of TRUE and FALSE. Is there anyway to put this output into columns?

Comment: Yup! So to assign to a new column, you'd do something like `df$my_new_var <- some_logic`. So you can use the `%in%` function with some `if...else` logic to assign to a new var. Worth nothing that since this needs to be vectorized, you'll want to look into the `ifelse` function, not just regular `if...else` logic.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `%in%` to check if one of the entries in the 'violent' vector is present in one of the 'Statute' column by looping overt those and `Reduce` the `list` of logical `vector` into a single `vector`

```
data$Type <-  c("Violent", "Non-Violent")[Reduce(`|`, 
             lapply(data[2:3], function(x) x %in% violent)) + 1]
data$Type
#[1] "Non-Violent" "Violent"     "Non-Violent"
```

---

As the above solution could be hard for a new user.  So, we can also do this by checking whether 'Statute' elements are `%in%` 'violent' or (`|`) 'Statute2' elements are `%in%` 'violent', use that in `ifelse` (for better understanding) to get the expected output

```
with(data, ifelse((Statute %in% violent) | 
               (Statute2 %in% violent), "Violent", "Non_Violent"))
#[1] "Violent"     "Non_Violent" "Violent"
```

NOTE: For hundreds of columns, the above method is not easier to implement.  We may need `Reduce` or `rowSums` (on a logical `vector`) to get the expected output

#### data

```
data <- structure(list(Person = 1:3, Statute = c("21 O.S. 1", "21 O.S. 14", 
 "22 O.S. 3"), Statute2 = c("22 O.S. 3", NA, NA)), .Names = c("Person", 
 "Statute", "Statute2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
 -3L))
```

Comment: They're clearly new to R, and you're throwing in things like `Reduce`? Why? Completely unnecessary for this task.

Comment: You should provide solutions fit for the audience receiving them instead of trying to show off.

Comment: @brittenb Well, what do you suggest here.  You just said `%in%` in the comments and you know that it wont work for multiple columns.  Basically, you are giving wrong info to a new user

Comment: I want to disincentivize providing complicated solutions to simple problems that do nothing to help the OP learn.

Comment: Thank you to you both! Honestly both were helpful and people tend to be a little rude to a newcomer on this site, so thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
cbind(data,
      Type = c("Non-Violent","Violent")[grepl(paste0(violent,collapse = "|"),do.call(paste,data))+1])
  Person    Statute  Statute2        Type
1      1  21 O.S. 1 22 O.S. 3     Violent
2      2 21 O.S. 14      <NA> Non-Violent
3      3  22 O.S. 3      <NA>     Violent
```